# Google Spreadsheet - add Date to cell depending upon the contents of another cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the following code to check column A for a certain value. (in this case ‘Work in progress’)  The date is added to the adjacent cell in column B.

What I want is that this only happens when the adjacent cell is empty. If a date is already in that cell, it needs to skip adding a new date.

```
function onEdit(e) {
    // Work in progress Begin Date  
    var colToWatch = 1, colToStamp = 2;
    var valueToWatch = "Work in progress"; 
    if (e.range.columnStart === colToWatch && (e.value === valueToWatch || typeof e.value == 'object'))
        e.source.getActiveSheet()
            .getRange(e.range.rowStart, colToStamp)
            .setValue(typeof e.value === 'object' ? null : new Date());
}
```

Comment: Change `e.range.columnStart` to `e.range.getColumn()`  I'd change the code to: `function onEdit(e) {
    // Work in progress Begin Date  
    var colToWatch = 1, colToStamp = 2;
    var valueToWatch = "Work in progress"; 
  
  if (e.range.getColumn() !== colToWatch) {return;} 
}`

Comment: Sorry doesn't do it for me,
It fills column B with a date, regardless of the value put in column A, 
Should only do this with the value “Work in progress”.
And still overwrites the date if already existing in column B ;(

Comment: Add another `if` test: Your code already locates the `Range` you want to test, you just need to store that range as a variable (optional, really, but it saves typing and follows D.R.Y. principle), use a `Range` method to **get** its **Value**, and compare that value to a value that means there was nothing, like an "empty string".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Apps Script with a Google Spreadsheet you can run some code when a cell is edited, and then check the column and value of the cell, and then either enter the date or not.

```
function onEdit(e) {//The letter "e" is used to get the event object
  var adjacentCell,rng,row,sh;//define variables without assigning a value

  var colToWatch = 1, colToStamp = 2;
  var valueToWatch = "Work in progress"; 

  rng = e.range;
  row = rng.getRow();

  if (rng.getColumn() !== colToWatch || e.value !== valueToWatch) {return;}

  sh = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  adjacentCell = sh.getRange(row,colToStamp).getValue();
  Logger.log('adjacentCell: ' + adjacentCell)
  Logger.log(!adjacentCell)

  if (adjacentCell) {return;}//If there is a value in cell then stop

  sh.getRange(row, colToStamp)
    .setValue(new Date());

}
```

Comment: Works now ! thanx